# What might cause SHChangeNotifyRegister to fail on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
SHChangeNotifyEntry changeentry = new SHChangeNotifyEntry();




        changeentry.pIdl = GetPidlFromFolderID(this.Handle, CSIDL.CSIDL_DESKTOP);
        changeentry.Recursively = true;


             uint notifyid = SHChangeNotifyRegister(
             this.Handle,
             SHCNF.SHCNF_PATHA ,
             SHCNE.SHCNE_ALLEVENTS,
             WM_SHNOTIFY,
             1,
             ref changeentry);
```

My code is crashing at the SHChangeNotifyRegister. I am trying to register a form for file change notification in Windows Mobile.

I think I may be passing incorrect parameters to SHChangeNotifyRegister.

Comment: Nativie exception occured in smaple.exe its says... its not even coming to catch block also..

Comment: Are you using PInvoke here? If so, you should at least show how you've defined SHChangeNotifyEnty, GetPidlFromFolderID and SHChangeNotifyRegister.
If SHChangeNotifyEntry is a class and not a struct the ref keyword in SHChangeNotifyRegister is wrong.

Comment: this is SHChangeNotifyEnty structure, 
public struct SHChangeNotifyEntry { public IntPtr pIdl; [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] public Boolean Recursively; } 
this is GetPidlFromFolderID .. 
public static IntPtr GetPidlFromFolderID(IntPtr hWnd, CSIDL Id) { IntPtr pIdl = IntPtr.Zero; SHGetFolderLocationReturnValues res = (SHGetFolderLocationReturnValues) SHGetSpecialFolderLocation( hWnd, Id, out pIdl); return (pIdl); }

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to reflect all the rejections in the comments. It will be more readable.

Comment: Can you show the Pinvoke signatures/structs you are using please?

Comment: friends.. i posted sample code here please see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470247/my-sample-app-is-getting-crash-while-registering-to-filechangeinfo-notification and let me know solution please

Answer (score 3):

pinvoke.net is handy for finding out dllimport and structure definitions, or at the very least getting a starting point for them :)

[SHChangeNotifyEntry](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SHChangeNotifyEntry.html)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
struct SHChangeNotifyEntry
{
    public IntPtr pIdl;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] public Boolean Recursively;
}
```

[SHChangeNotifyRegister](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHChangeNotifyRegister.html)

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true, EntryPoint="#2", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern UInt32 SHChangeNotifyRegister(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            SHCNF fSources,
            SHCNE fEvents,
            uint wMsg,
            int cEntries,
            ref SHChangeNotifyEntry pFsne)
```

As others have said, try posting the dllimports you have, and the structure definitions that you are passing into the p/invokes, and the exact error messages/exceptions you are getting.

Comment: I have to add that these are for the desktop rather than device, I've since got the device working as an answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470247/my-sample-app-is-getting-crash-while-registering-to-filechangeinfo-notification)